# WCF - Visual Studio Won't Generate SVC file

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I have a very annoying problem which I *think* is somehow related to certificates, though I am not sure...

I have two developer machines - my new machine A and my old development machine B.
I have a WCF project that is 100% identical on both.

However, when I try to publish using A, the necessary SVC file isn't generated, but it is on B.

For now, this is not a huge issue - I can just publish through B - but it IS very annoying.

Because the code for the two are entirely identical, I am think it's something about the environment on A that's the problem.

I'm thinking certificates, most likely.

We have the following in the App.config for the service:

```
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="*.ourcompany.dk" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"/>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="OurWebservice.UserNameValidator, OurWebservice"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
```

I've added the certificate to my personal store on A, however, and followed the guide on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702621.aspx to make sure WCF can access it. Still no joy.

I'm pretty much at my wits end here - I have no idea how to even debug this!
VS2010 doesn't even give me a warning when I publish - it just doesn't create the SVC file..!

Thansk in advance!

Comment: Turned out I had installed my X.509 certificate under my current user, rather than the machine.

Once I fixed that, everything worked!

Comment: I have the same issue.. but it happens once in a while.. Can you provide me the steps for your solution??

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but my solution was to add back the

```
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/servicename/" />
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

to my app.config